# Average of distinct account per category

Tags: powerbi, dax, average

I'm trying to do a calculation in Power BI with DAX.
I'm going to tackle the calculation step by step:

1. I'd like first to filter the calculation on the category1
2. Then, I'd like to get the sum of distinct accounts per server
3. With these results, I would need to get the average based on previous results.

I know the explanation is not the best so here is the result, I'd like, based on this table:

| category1 | account | server |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nobaz | account1 | server1 |
| baz | account2 | server1 |
| baz | account2 | server2 |
| baz | account2 | server2 |
| baz | account4 | server3 |
| baz | account5 | server3 |

So here I'd like to select only 'baz', then count the distinct accounts per server:

- 1 in server1
- 1 in server 2
- 2 in server 3

And then, I'd like to get the average of the number of accounts per server (here it would be 1,33 ((1+1+2)/3))

Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Measure =
VAR _accountCount =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTX (
            GROUPBY ( fct2, fct2[account], fct2[category1], fct2[server] ),
            [account]
        ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( fct2, fct2[category1] )
    )
VAR _serverCount =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( fct2[server] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( fct2, fct2[category1] )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( _accountCount, _serverCount )
```

[image: Solution]

`Only buz Count`

```
Measure 2 = 
VAR _accountCount =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTX (
            GROUPBY ( FILTER(fct2, fct2[category1]="baz"),fct2[account], fct2[category1], fct2[server] ),
            [account]
        ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( fct2, fct2[category1] )
    )
VAR _serverCount =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( fct2[server] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( fct2, fct2[category1] )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( _accountCount, _serverCount )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!! 
However the result I would like is the average of distinct accounts ,per servername, by taking only accounts with 'baz' as category. Moreover, I'd need to have this average without taking the amount of accounts for the blank server.

Could you help me one more time with it?

Comment: Only baz count provided